# calling a c++ function from java which uses some other function which refers include files

Tags: java, java-native-interface

i am trying to call a navite method defined in c++ from java, the function which i am trying to call refers some functions defined in header files and also the other functions defined by me... is it passible to call that?.. i am getting an error "error LNK2019-unresolved external symbol".. can any one help me to do this...

Comment: I'd guess that the library you are trying to link against also requires additional libraries/obj files?

Comment: i am trying to include the "windows.h" and "fstream.h" include files.. i am trying to call the functions which i have defined for all the functions i am getting the same error...

Comment: Have you compiled your function to a dll? You should then put the dll to a location where Java can load it. If I recall correctly, these places are something like the root directory of your application and the location where the shared libraries are.

Comment: i couldn't create dll itself... while trying to create it only i am getting this error... i just got .obj file alone while i am trying to do so with "cl" command in vc++ command prompt...

Comment: You need to be able to compile and link to a DLL for it to work. Writing JNI code is tricky and memory management is hard. I would start with a simple tutorial on JNI ( http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html ) and then expand from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)? It's much simpler compared to JNI.

Comment: thank you for your response... i am new to both the concepts i will refer about JNA and will share by experience... is that any way to do this in JNI...